# Apple rejected the binary (2.3.1 - Performance) React Native 0.61.0-rc.3

Tags: ios, react-native

My first app with React Native to the Apple App Store has been rejected because they say, "... it contains hidden features, hidden features. Specifically, your app includes support for Hot Update functionality that allows your app to download a new main.jsbundle anytime. It would be appropriate to remove this functionality from your app￼."

It's a fairly simple app with a search to Firebase Realtime database for jobs.

I've spent hours scouring the net for answers, have about 4 Case numbers with Apple requesting specific information as to exactly where it sees the problem - still waiting.

Has anyone encountered and solved this problem? Detailed message from Apple below.

> Guideline 2.3.1 - Performance
>
> We discovered that your app contains hidden features.
>
> Specifically, your app includes support for Hot Update functionality
>   that allows your app to download a new main.jsbundle anytime. It would
>   be appropriate to remove this functionality from your app.
>
> The next submission of this app may require a longer review time, and
>   this app will not be eligible for an expedited review until this issue
>   is resolved.
>
> Next Steps
>
> - Review the Performance section of the App Store Review Guidelines.
> - Ensure your app is compliant with all sections of the App Store Review Guidelines and the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer
>     Program.
> - Once your app is fully compliant, resubmit your app for review.
>
> Submitting apps designed to mislead or harm customers or evade the
>   review process may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   Program account. Review the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer
>   Program to learn more about our policies regarding termination.
>
> Guideline 2.5.2 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> Your app, extension, or linked framework appears to contain code
>   designed explicitly with the capability to change your app’s behavior
>   or functionality after App Review approval, which is not in compliance
>   with App Store Review Guideline 2.5.2 and section 3.3.2 of the Apple
>   Developer Program License Agreement.
>
> This code, combined with a remote resource, can facilitate significant
>   changes to your app’s behavior compared to when it was initially
>   reviewed for the App Store. While you may not be using this
>   functionality currently, it has the potential to load private
>   frameworks, private methods, and enable future feature changes. This
>   includes any code which passes arbitrary parameters to dynamic methods
>   such as dlopen(), dlsym(), respondsToSelector:, performSelector:,
>   method_exchangeImplementations(), and running remote scripts in order
>   to change app behavior and/or call SPI, based on the contents of the
>   downloaded script. Even if the remote resource is not intentionally
>   malicious, it could easily be hijacked via a Man In The Middle (MiTM)
>   attack, which can pose a serious security vulnerability to users of
>   your app.
>
> The next submission of this app may require a longer review time, and
>   this app will not be eligible for an expedited review until this issue
>   is resolved.
>
> Next Steps
>
> - Review the Software Requirements section of the App Store Review Guidelines.
> - Ensure your app is compliant with all sections of the App Store Review Guidelines and the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer
>     Program.
> - Once your app is fully compliant, resubmit your app for review.
>
> Submitting apps designed to mislead or harm customers or evade the
>   review process may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   Program account. Review the Terms & Conditions of the Apple Developer
>   Program to learn more about our policies regarding termination.

Comment: Did you generate a development IPA? My react native production builds don't have hot reloading support, I thought this was only available in developer builds/debug mode.

Comment: I've looked everywhere that I am aware of and changed Debug to Release. In AppDelegate I've commented out the Debug option.


 //return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil]

Comment: You can leave that code, there's no reason to edit any of that out. It's more related to the way you create your IPA. Did your use XCode to create an archive (IPA)? Or another tool? If using XCode, make sure you have the right "Scheme" selected too.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've selected all the scheme build types and changed them to Release. I was uploading directly to the "App Store Connect" from Xcode in the "Distribute App" option. You've given me an idea though. I will select "Ad Hoc" instead, where you choose the method of distribution of the IPA, and install it manually to the simulator and see if the “Fast Refresh” is still activated

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED. About 8 months ago, new to RN and trying to update RN, I found a recommendation to install react-native-update. This is now called react-native-pushy in github and the instructions are in Chinese. However, if you paste them into Google translate, they talk about adding a config file to disable it in iOS. I removed it completely and the App Store approved it